# Finding the number of tasks waiting to poll from ArrayBlockingQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an ArrayBlockingQueue with several connections to the database. Many threads try to get connection from it by polling from it. The maximum connections available in the queue is 50, after 50, the threads have to wait for the connections to be put back so as to acquire a connection to database.

The problem is the I am not able to get the number of threads waiting at this ArrayBlockingQueue to get db connection. I looked at the documentation there doesn't seem to be anything relevant to what I want, since the tasks who want to acquire db connections are threads I am not sure how to manually count the number of tasks waiting for a db connection.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need/want to know?

Comment: I am doing performance tests.

Comment: Why do you have an `ABQ` of database connections? Do you have a home made connection pool? Getting that information from the `ABQ` is nigh impossible, but most connection pools would provide you with plenty of statistics about the pool state.

Comment: yes I have a home made connection pool using array blocking queue, it is a requirement unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using reflection the only thing I can think of is intercepting the calls to any poll/remove methods in the ABQ.  You can extend the ABQ, have some counter that increments prior to invoking it's super counterpart, then finally decrementing.

```
private final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
// if you are using Java 8 I would prefer LongAddr
public T poll(){
   count.incrementAndGet();
   try {
        return super.poll()
   }finally{
      count.decrementAndGet();
   }
}
```

Comment: Lol, no answers for 2 hours then we both post the same thing 30 seconds apart.

Comment: So as long as the thread is not able to poll,it will be inside the try block,and once it can poll it goes to finally?

Comment: That's right.  The `poll` does throw `InterruptedException`.  So the correct way to phrase it is 'A decrement of the counter is a result if either an element in the queue or interruption'

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `ArrayBlockingQueue` with your own class for testing purposes and have an `AtomicInteger` in the class.

Increment the `AtomicInteger` when a new thread waits, decrement it when one finishes.

You can now log or view the value of that `AtomicInteger` however and whenever you like.